# how to multiple scatter plots from multiple dataframes by using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to plot scatter graphs in subplots from multiple data frames using for loop.
Here's my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4] # data frames in a list
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0, 0].scatter(df1['column1'], df1['column2'])
ax[0, 0].plot(df1['column1'], df1['column3'], 'r-')
ax[0, 1].scatter(df2['column1'], df2['column2'])
ax[0, 1].plot(df2['column1'], df2['column3'], 'r-')
ax[1, 0].scatter(df3['column1'], df3['column2'])
ax[1, 0].plot(df3['column1'], df3['column3'], 'r-')
ax[1, 1].scatter(df4['column1'], df4['column2'])
ax[1, 1].plot(df4['column1'], df4['column3'], 'r-')
```

I want 4 subplots having one line plot and one scatter one each subplot.
So, I wrote the for loop codes like below.

```
nrow=2
ncol=2
count = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol, figsize=(20,10))

for r in range(nrow):
    for c in range(ncol):
        ax[nrow, ncol].scatter(df_list[count]['Serial Number'], df_list[count]['Measurement Data']))
        count=+1
```

but, the error came out.

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

I figured out why error occurred. The correct one is below.

```
for r in range(nrow):
    for c in range(ncol):
        ax[r, c].scatter(df_list[count]['Serial Number'], df_list[count]['Measurement Data']))
        count=+1
```

Comment: So you want to have scatter plots from multiple datasets in the same plot? Or something else? Could you edit the question and example code to be more clear on what you want to acheive?

Comment: In your code, you are doing a scatter plot of columns 1 and 2 from one dataframe and a line plot of columns 1 and 3 from another dataframe.  To use a for loop effectively, you need to do similar things to all dataframes.  For example, they all need to have 2 columns or you should select the same 2 columns from each one.

Comment: @DaehyeokKang: Do you always have 4 dataframes or can it be more? A solution for n dataframes where n is even should be quite easy.

Comment: @Shaido I figured out what I missed. Thanks

Comment: @DaehyeokKang: Nice, you can post the answer as an answer instead of in the question and then accept it to mark the question as answered.

Comment: See here regarding self-answering a question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow